# Linq to XML single or default

Tags: asp.net, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I am querying an `xml` and i am storing the results using `singleordefault`

```
    var query = from nm in xelement.Descendants("EmployeeFinance")
                where (int)nm.Element("EmpPersonal_Id") == empID
                select new AllowancePaid
                {
                    gradeTaxId = nm.Element("Allow-GradeTax").Elements("Amount").Attributes("BenListId").Select(a => (int)a).ToList(),
                    gradeTaxAmt = nm.Element("Allow-GradeTax").Elements("Amount").Select(a => (double)a).ToList()
                };
    Debug.WriteLine("2");
    var resultquery = query.SingleOrDefault();
```

now this line: `var resultquery = query.SingleOrDefault();` works fine if it found in the `xml` file. However, i have a case where my query will result in a null. If i have no value, it would make an entry in the `xml` file and my query obviously results in `null`. My question is how do i cater for this without causing my programe to crash. obviously, `singleordefault()` doesnt work.

*************************** EDITED *********************************************

I read what everyone said so far and it make sense but i am still having  a problem.

```
    if (query.Count() == 0)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("NULL");


    }
    else {
        var resultquery = query.SingleOrDefault();             
        Debug.WriteLine("NOT NULL");
    }
```

OR

```
        if (query == null)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("NULL");


        }
        else {
            var resultquery = query.SingleOrDefault();             
            Debug.WriteLine("NOT NULL");
        }
```

OR

```
   var resultquery = query.SingleOrDefault();
    if (resultquery == null)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("NULL Result");
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("NOT NULL");
    }
```

I am getting a `System.NullReferenceException` error when the first part of the if statement is true. One user said to do this: `var resultquery = query.SingleOrDefault();` then use my if..else statement to do the comparison. However i am getting the error at the point of assign `query.singleofdefault()` to `resultquery`. So i am lost.. hope someone can help. thank you

Comment: Why don't you check for `null` and just insert the value if it is?

Comment: I have edited your Title and Tags to reflect that this is specific to `Linq-to-XML` not `Linq-to-Entities`

Comment: how do i check for null?

Comment: what i am trying to understand is this. the documentation states if the result query is 0 it will give a default value, if it is not, it will be a  single value. so why doesnt this give a default value?

Comment: You're returning an instance of a class based on the query.  If the query returns no results, you get the default value for a class (which is a reference type) - which is **null**.

Comment: @Tim please check the edit section for the question. I am still having some problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what i am trying to understand is this. the documentation states if the result query is 0 it will give a default value, if it is not, it will be a single value. so why doesnt this give a default value? [taken from the comments]

`null` *is* the default value for reference types. Apparently `AllowancePaid` is a reference type (a custom `class`).

Comment: please check the edit section for the question. I am still having some problems.

Answer (score 1):

What is the value you want when the there is no value found.

You could either do:

```
if (resultquery == null) { 
   // Logic for No result
} else {
   // Logic for result found
}
```

Or you could force a default value

eg.

```
 var resultquery = query.SingleOrDefault() ?? new AllowancePaid();
```

**UPDATE**

From the comments posted it appears that the null reference exception is actually caused within the query itself rather than by the assignment to resultquery and use of later.

This updated query should solve the issue

```
var query = from nm in xelement.Descendants("EmployeeFinance")
            where  nm.Element("EmpPersonal_Id") != null 
                   && (int)nm.Element("EmpPersonal_Id") == empID
                   && nm.Element("Allow-GradeTax") != null
                   && nm.Element("Allow-GradeTax").Elements("Amount") != null
            select new AllowancePaid
            {
                gradeTaxId = nm.Element("Allow-GradeTax").Elements("Amount").Attributes("BenListId").Select(a => (int)a).ToList(),
                gradeTaxAmt = nm.Element("Allow-GradeTax").Elements("Amount").Select(a => (double)a).ToList()
            };

var resultquery = query.SingleOrDefault();

if (resultquery == null) { 
  Debug.WriteLine("NULL Result");
} else {
   // Logic here
}
```

Comment: what i am trying to understand is this. the documentation states if the result query is 0 it will give a default value, if it is not, it will be a single value. so why doesnt this give a default value?

Comment: @DineshPersaud - As I put in my comment, null *is* the default value for a reference type.

Comment: @DineshPersaud It does give the default value.  The default value for a class is `null`. If your query return an integer the value would be 0 as 0 is the default value for int.  To test put `var test = default(AllowancePaid)`  test will equal null.

Comment: `   if (query == null)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("NULLL");
            }
            else
            {
                var resultquery = query.Single();`

Comment: @DineshPersaud No you are checking the wrong variable.  `var resultquery = query.SingleOrDefault(); if (resultQuery == null) { Debug.....`

Comment: it gives an error still because im trying to insert a null value into resultquery. i still get the same error.

Comment: @DineshPersaud No it won't be that, queries are not executed immediately, the SingleOrDefault() forces it to execute - hence the null reference exception.  I've updated the answer with some extra null reference checks that should make the query execute.

Comment: @BobVale please check the updates i added to the question .. under edit heading. thank you

Comment: using your code i got the following: A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in SSPModel.dll
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.